# How to query SELECT WHERE EXISTS... in django

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I have a problem with django models, I don't know how to create a query...

I have three classes/models:

- A has just name (and id)
- B has name, id and foreign key to A
- C has foreign key to B among other field.

So every C has its A (while every A can have more As) but doesn't have its foreign key directly - it has to go through B.

I have a subset of Cs got by another query. Now I want to select such As for which there is a C in the subset. What do I do?

Comment: Btw, make sure you read the [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) site, apart from explaining how this site is different from a usual forum (e.g. voting), you also get a shiny welcome badge ;)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you possibly post here relevant parts of the code [you already have](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible due to licensing issues.

Comment: You don't have to post the exact code, but a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) always [helps others helping you help us all](http://thankyouforhelpingushelpyouhelpusall.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `c_subset` is subset of `C` objects that you have, to get `A`s which has these `C`s 
you can do

```
>>> A.objects.filter(b__c__in = c_subset)
```

Comment: This works but it adds a lot of queries (according to debug-toolbar) and slows the application. Could you please add some explanation what exactly does it do and how? Thanks

Comment: @djangonoob, Its pretty straight forward. `__` follows the relationship, and `__in` looks within a list. Django reference as nice explanations.

Comment: Bu it should add one new query, right? It's not in a loop or something and it's called once when my view is called/used/refreshed.